# Electrical? Idk what it could be

Tags: acura

I have a 1999 acura cl 3.0 and i was driving down the road and my car shuts off and it gets kinda hard to steer, ill pull over put it in park and it will start back up and sometimes do it again. I was driving on the freeway just now and it did it again, i just got it smogged and it passed then the next day is when this started.

Comment: You'll need to check for codes. There isn't really enough information here for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: The hardness to steer occurs because you have hydraulic power steering and there is no energy storage system in it like there is for brake assist. So, the symptom really is that the engine shuts off, and the hardness to steer is a corollary of that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a 98 cl that did the same thing! It was a worn out ignition. If I would hit a bump just right, the ignition would turn from ON to Accessory. Fortunately mine was the 5 speed so I could just turn the ignition back on and bump start it. Next time it happens, look to see what position your ignition is in.

If you do need a new ignition, it will probably be a pricey repair and require new keys. Man I miss my cl, great car.